# Popup boxes are not centered like they're supposed to be

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just recently implemented popup boxes into my javascript game project; however, instead of being centered like they're suppose to, they will sometimes show up in incorrect positions (mainly all the way to the right of the page).

**See example of correct position:**

[image: http://puu.sh/5YT8G.png]

**See example of incorrect position:**

[image: http://puu.sh/5YT2T.png]

Here is the popup function that is called:

```
//buttons can be an object or string
//if string (any string), will use default button
function popup(title,message,buttons,time){
    $('#popup p[name="title"]').text(title);
    $('#popup div[name="content"]').html(message);
    $('#popup span[name="buttons"] :not(button[name="continue"])').remove();
    $('#popup span[name="buttons"] button').hide();

    if(buttons != null){
        if(typeof buttons == 'object'){
            //snip
        }else{
            $('#popup button[name="continue"]').show();
        }
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#popup').hide(750);
        },(time+750));
    }

    //center
    $('#popup').position({
        my : 'center',
        at : 'center',
        of: $('body')
    });

    $('#popup').show(750);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Did you try this. make it to position: absolute**

since i can't see your actual html layout design. i would suggest you to try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#popup").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2,
        "z-index": 2000 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //buttons can be an object or string
    //if string (any string), will use default button
    function popup(title, message, buttons, time) {
        $('#popup p[name="title"]').text(title);
        $('#popup div[name="content"]').html(message);
        $('#popup span[name="buttons"] :not(button[name="continue"])').remove();
        $('#popup span[name="buttons"] button').hide();

        if (buttons != null) {
            if (typeof buttons == 'object') {
                //snip
            } else {
                $('#popup button[name="continue"]').show();
            }
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#popup').hide(750);
            }, (time + 750));
        }

        //center
        $('#popup').position({
            my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
            of: $('body')
        });

        $('#popup').show(750);
    }
    $('#popup').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'left': '0', 'right': '0', 'bottom': '0', 'top': '0', 'margin': 'auto' });
});
```

Comment: And what am I suppose to do for mobile support?

Comment: you can also add this as a css under media query like
#popup{ position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0; margin:auto;}